# SafariではJavascript Bindメソッドが動作しないですか

Tags: javascript

Bind という機能を利用しようと思ったんですが、うまくいかなくて質問します。

SafariではJavascriptのBindメソッドを利用できないですか

```
return (
  <div className="App">
        <header>
          <h1>
            <a href="/" onClick={function (e) {
              console.log(e);
              e.preventDefault();
              this.setState({
                mode : 'read'
              });

            }.bind(this)}>
              {this.state.subject.title}
            </a>
          </h1>
        </header>
      <TOC contents={this.state.contents}/>
      <Content title={_title} desc={_desc} />
  </div>
);
```

Comment: ミスしました。
this.setState =({
                mode : 'read'
              });ではなくて
this.setState({
                mode : 'read'
              });
ですね

Comment: Safariでも、（7年前からずっとアップデートしていない等でなければ）bindを使用できます。ですから、bind以外にうまくいかない原因があると思います。　うまくいかないというのはどういう状況でしょうか？　また、エラーメッセージなどはありますか？　これらの情報を追加していただけると答えられるかもしれません。質問は「編集」ができますのでぜひ情報を追加してみてください。

Comment: ありがとうございました！今は原因わかってて解決しました。bindの問題ではなくReactのthis.setStateの問題でした！